# Generating a random number with specific amount of digits and sum_of_digits (Python 3.8)

Tags: python

I want to generate a random number with a specific amount of digits (specified by user) and those digits should have a specific sum that has been specified by the user. I have tried assigning a variable to the command **random.randint(x,y)** and then checking the *len()* and *sum()* of that variable if it is equal to the one specified by the user but it hasn't resulted in something useful. The code that I have tried looks something like this:

```
required_length = input()
required_sum = input()
z = random.randint(0 , 99999)
number = z
length = len(z)
sum1 = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(number))
if length == required_length and sum1 == required_sum:
     print(z)
```

To help if I haven't been specific enough, let's say I want to generate a number **that should have 7 digits**, and **the sum of those 7 digits should be 7**. One of those random numbers could be 1121101. I hope this example helped.

See you soon all, and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This might not be a random number at all. For example, N digits, with sum 1, you have only one choice. I'd suggest to come up with an algorithm to construct a number of your liking.

Comment: can the number start with zeros? do you want an integer or a string?

Comment: @norok2 pick a random one of a pool of numbers which match the criteria.

Comment: @DanielF the point is how do you build such pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple solution

You can create a list of numbers which can be generated and then use `random.choice()` function to choose 1 element from list.

```py
import random

n = int(input("Amount of digits: "))
x = int(input("Sum of digits: "))
numbers = [num for num in range(10 ** (n - 1), 10 ** n) if sum(map(int, str(num))) == x]
print(random.choice(numbers))
```

#### Fast solution

```py
import random

t = []

def f(s, i):
    r = sum(map(int, s))
    if i == n:
        if r == x:
            t.append(s)
    else:
        for q in range(10) if len(s) else range(1, 10):
            if r + q <= x:
                f(s + str(q), i + 1)

n = int(input("Amount of digits: "))
x = int(input("Sum of digits: "))

f("", 0)
print(random.choice(t))
```

Comment: Did you try your code? I got `61` as result when `n=7` and `x=7`.

Comment: First of all, using global variables like you did in your second example is not a good practice, and secondly, when the list of numbers is empty, an IndexError will be raised.

Comment: IndexError is raised for example when n = 2 and x = 19

Comment: I know, but the question has not any instructions for cases where numbers can not be generated.

Comment: Could you explain what "s" and "i" function parameters are for?

Comment: @Ratery Thanks for your answer. It does work. I'll just have to make it compatible with any requested "n" and "x" number given by the user. But, without all the other people's help this wouldn't be possible so, big thanks to the others too!

Comment: What I tried to say on my comment was that it should work for any range of numbers, because numbers greater than 10 don't seem to work.

Comment: By the way @Ratery is it okay if I mention you on my project's credits? And sorry for interrupting anything.

Comment: @noExplorer, Yes, it’s OK.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by fast here, but if I run it with a number of digits `n = 9` and a sum of the digits `s = 80` it computes for at least minutes...

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go on this would be to generate a number  on a digit by digit basis, where each digit is random within the given constraints.

The idea is that one should pick for a given digit a random number (between 0 and 9 included) except when the outcome could result in a violation of the constraints, in which case the range from which to pick the random number shall be reduced accordingly.

In other words, each digit is picked among the allowed values given the "remaining" sum and number of digits.

To simplify the computation I work on lists of digits and I provide some function to convert from list of digits to integer and viceversa.
Note that for incompatible num of digits and sum value, an empty list is produced.

```
import random


def seq_to_int(seq, base=10):
    """Convert sequence of digits to an integer."""
    result = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(reversed(seq)):
        if 0 <= x < base:
            result += x * base ** i
        else:
            msg = f"Invalid value in `seq` for given `base`"
            raise ValueError(msg)
    return result


def int_to_seq(n, base=10):
    """Convert an integer to a sequence of digits."""
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    elif n < 0:
        raise ValueError("`n` must be non-negative.")
    else:
        result = []
        while n:
            result.append(n % base)
            n //= base
        return result[::-1]


def random_digits_given_sum(num_digits, sum_value, base=10):    
    digits = []
    max_digit = base - 1
    if sum_value > max_digit * num_digits:
        return digits
    sum_left = sum_value
    num_left = num_digits
    while num_left > 0:
        if sum_left > max_digit:
            min_rand = max(0, sum_left - max_digit * (num_left - 1))
            max_rand = max_digit
            digit = random.randint(min_rand, max_rand)
        elif sum_left >= 0 and num_left > 1:
            min_rand = 0
            max_rand = sum_left
            digit = random.randint(min_rand, max_rand)
        elif sum_left >= 0 and num_left == 1:
            digit = sum_left
        else:
            raise ValueError        
        digits.append(digit)
        sum_left -= digit
        num_left -= 1
    # ensure first digit is not 0
    if digits[0] == 0:
        non_zero_indices = [i for i, digit in enumerate(digits) if digit]
        i = random.choice(non_zero_indices)
        digits[0], digits[i] = digits[i], digits[0]
    # shuffle remaining digits
    shuffled = digits[1:]
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    return digits[0:1] + shuffled
```

Below some code to test that it is actually working:

```
random.seed(0)
n = 2  # number of random inputs to gets
k = 4  # number of different generations
for _ in range(n):
    num_digits = random.randint(1, 16)
    sum_value = random.randint(1, num_digits * 9)
    for _ in range(k):
        digits = random_digits_given_sum(num_digits, sum_value)
        print(digits, seq_to_int(digits), sum(digits), sum(digits) == sum_value)
```

with the following output:

```
[6, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 9] 6889880999969 98 True
[5, 9, 4, 7, 9, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9] 5947956999899 98 True
[8, 1, 9, 8, 2, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9] 8198299799999 98 True
[4, 2, 9, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5] 4297899999995 98 True
[6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9, 9] 699999999999499 127 True
[4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 9] 499999999999969 127 True
[3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9] 399997999999999 127 True
[9, 7, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9] 975999998989999 127 True
```

showing that it is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your approach to this, however I would like to know what the number behind the "True" means. Tested it and it does return a lot in a short period of time even on big demands (Like 239). Otherwise this is very functional. By the way, I haven't been in the coding 'realm' for long time so that is why I am asking.

Comment: @noExplorer `True` gets printed every time a the actual sum of the digits matches the requested one (`sum(digits) == sum_value`). Also, if you think this answer is helpful, you may consider upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks. I did try upvoting it but I lack the required karmapoints (I got 13). Also, when I specify the n and k number as 239, it returns 789 behind the "True".

Comment: `n` and `k` refer to the number of tests as per the comments next to them. The tests themselves generate random numbers for the number of digits and their expected sum, and are given as input to `random_digits_given_sum()`. If you have specific inputs in mind just give them to that function directly.

Comment: Did try it, thing is every result given to the user is False. The edit I did is:                             random.seed(0)
x = int(input("Please specify Digit Amount "))
c = int(input("Please specify Digit Sum "))
n = 2  # number of random inputs to gets
k = 4  # number of different generations
for _ in range(n):
    num_digits = random.randint(1, 16)
    sum_value = random.randint(1, num_digits * 9)
    for _ in range(k):
        digits = random_digits_given_sum(x, c)
        print(digits, seq_to_int(digits), sum(digits), sum(digits) == sum_value)

Comment: @noExplorer The test code is only for testing, you should not use it for anything else. Given the function defined above, the equivalent code for the original question could be: `required_length = int(input()); required_sum = int(input()); z = seq_to_int(random_digits_given_sum(required_length, required_sum)); print(z)` and the random number satisfying your criteria is `z`. If no number exists, matching the criteria, the result gets to be `0`.